# How to avoid disorder when calling future.cancel()?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, threadpool

Here is the thing.

First, I have a thread pool in java (e.g., a thread pool has 8 threads).

Second, I have another monitor thread to limit that the execution time of each thread in this pool cannot be larger than 5 minutes via future.cancel() method.

However, I figure out a potential disorder under the situation below.

Assume, thread t1 in this pool has executed over 5 minutes, and monitor thread has observed this situation. 
At the same time, thread t1 finished its current computation task and accepted another new computation task; monitor thread calls future.cancel() to send the interrupt signal to thread t1.

Unfortunately, thread t1 checks its interrupt signal and cancel this new task, which is not our expectation.

The question is how to avoid this situation? Any advice?

Comment: How are you measuring execution time?

Comment: @shmosel, monitor thread calls getThreadCPUTime(id) to get the execution time for specific thread, e.g., thread t1's id is 2, then monitor thread will call getThreadCPUTime(2).

Comment: Why would you do that if you're trying to measure execution time of individual tasks? Or am I misunderstanding the requirement?

Comment: @shmosel yes! I think you are right. I can check (thread.interrupt() && thread execution time > 5 min) in thread t1's checking point. I just feel tired of java "soft" interrupt mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you need some kind of "atomic" cancellation of task. But I don't know if this is possible, so I have another idea:

You can inverse logic, so Monitor will check the time of execution, then set some kind of "flag" in thread. And thread can check this flag in it's logic of task execution.

Comment: Also, try to get some metrics of your question-case. Is it real situation in your app?

Comment: Yes, I encountered a real problem in my app. But I'm not sure whether the root cause is this concurrency bug. Besides, you talked about "flag". Actually, Java uses the same way to stop a thread via writing and reading the flag named "interrupt" which I have already used in my app.